# onOptionsItemSelected not called when using device api level 14 (SherlockActionBar)

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

This is `SherlockActionBar` Sample,it's used static attachment,I run to `ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH` device,but method `onOptionsItemSelected` not called!

Excess part of the code is deleted, 3.x and 2.x versions tried no problem，help me~~

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(SampleList.THEME); // Used for theme switching in samples
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mSherlock
            .setUiOptions(ActivityInfo.UIOPTION_SPLIT_ACTION_BAR_WHEN_NARROW);
    mSherlock.setContentView(R.layout.text);

    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text))
            .setText(R.string.static_attach_content);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
    return mSherlock.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Used to put dark icons on light action bar
    boolean isLight = SampleList.THEME == R.style.Theme_Sherlock_Light;

    menu.add("Save")...

    menu.add("Search")...

    menu.add("Refresh")...

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (mSherlock.dispatchKeyEvent(event)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Log.i("", "on options item selected!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    Toast.makeText(this, item.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: do you add a custom view to your menu button?

Comment: @TomislavNovoselec this sample no add.

Comment: oh!!I find!!i forget overwrite Activity.onOptionsItemSelected!!!!hahaha

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Fragments and calling `onOptionsItemSelected` in fragment and in activity remember to return `super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);` in activity call

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // If home icon is clicked return to main Activity
    case android.R.id.home:
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null,
                FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: I find the reason,i forget override onOptionsItemSelected,and dispatch to sherlock...but thank you!

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the only working solution when using fragments.